# Get count of months from given mysql result

Tags: php

I am trying to get the amount of users registered by month to insert it into a chart.js The problem that I am having is to display the count result  per month.

I get the following results from mysql query

php `print_r($this->results);`

results

```
Array (
  [0] => Array
    (
        [d] => 2018-05-15 21:54:08
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [d] => 2018-05-16 15:50:58
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
        [d] => 2018-06-18 18:27:11
    )

)
```

The answer should be: 05=2 and 06=1

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's the query? Where do you define the logic for translating the query results into an array of months? Have you even tried that yet? You're missing a lot of information here.

Comment: Hi Tim, that's exactly what I want to avoid, it needs to be done by php and not by mysql query. What else am I missing in terms to be more explicit?

Comment: If it needs to be done in PHP, you need to show what you've tried. Someone else has given you an answer, but keep in mind that Stackoverflow is not a coding service; we help you debug **your** code, so try to attempt something first, then post questions with specific issues.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I know how it works, and I am not looking for a given code answer, I am trying to approach the answer. Thanks anyway for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
$data = [];
$data[0]['d'] = '2018-05-15 21:54:08';
$data[1]['d'] = '2018-05-16 15:50:58';
$data[2]['d'] = '2018-06-18 18:27:11';

$result = [];
foreach( $data as $element ) {
    // convert date to timestramp by strToTime
    // get month via date( 'm' )
    $month = date( 'm', strToTime( $element['d'] ) );

    // if a count for month is present increment it
    if( isset( $result[$month] )) {
        $result[$month]++;
    } else { // if NO count is present, create and set to 1
        $result[$month] = 1;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
```

**Result**

```
array(2) {
  ["05"]=>
  int(2)
  ["06"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

**Edit**

added explaination

Comment: Thanks Pilan, so it looks like I can do a for to loop over the result array, am I correct? the if (month) incremental is something I do not understand very well how it finds the month, does it print the month as 1 when nothing is found? THANKS!!!

Comment: @Jorge added comments so you can understand better whats happening

Comment: Ohh ok, got it, what it does is adding the final count number of the value.
Thank you very much for the comments. THANKS!!!